# How to install git daemon on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, git-daemon

I'm sharing my repository on my

```
Linux nozim-desktop 2.6.32-24-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 16 14:17:33 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

and I when I run:

```
sudo -u git git-daemon --base-path=/home/git/repositories/ --export-all
```

it says:

```
sudo: git-daemon: command not found
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ubuntu 12.04, the following line worked for me out of the box (execute it in the Git repository you want to share):

```
git daemon --export-all --base-path=$(pwd)
```

To clone the shared repository, use

```
git clone git://HOSTNAME/ REPOSITORY_NAME
# e.g., git clone git://my-machine/ test-project
```

Note that the`/` after the hostname is required.

Answer (score 5):

After encountering the same problem on my Ubuntu 10.04 system, I learned that git-daemon was just installed somewhere else and operated differently than the guide I followed on setting it up was expecting it to.

On my system, it was located at `/us/lib/git-core/git-daemon`

To use it, edit the file `/etc/service/git-daemon/run/` and modify the parameters to suit your needs.

Here is mine:

`#!/bin/sh

exec 2>&1

echo 'git-daemon starting.'

exec chpst -ugitdaemon 
/usr/lib/git-core/git-daemon --verbose --base-path=/home/git/repositories`

If you want all of your repositories to be available publicly, add `--export-all`, otherwise, run `touch git-daemon-export-ok` within the `/path/to/repositories/<repository-name>.git/` directory of the repositories you do want to be available publicly.

After making your changes, run `ps -A | grep 'git'` and then run a `kill <process-id>` to reload `git-daemon` with your new configuration.

Hope that helps!

**Source:** http://sharplearningcurve.com/blog/post/2010/02/06/Chasing-The-CI-Grail-e28093-Setup-Gitosis-From-Scratch.aspx ("Update Git-Daemon Configuration")

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Git#Making_available_public_cloning_of_the_projects

It solved my problem.